# QGIS 2.6.1 plugin repository, is it broken?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

In QGIS 2.6.1 the plugin repository is unavailable. The URL is:

http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml

Is there an alternative plugin repository, or a way to resolve it? Have tried two different computers, and still cannot download plugins.

Comment: I can attest that plugins are still available for 2.18.28.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a "s" after http to get https, and it will work again.